# Subdomain Routing Issue in Laravel

Tags: laravel, subdomain

Laravel Subdomain Issue :

1. Create subdomain
2. Upload projects to the domain
3. Move file form public folder
4. Configure index.php
5. subdomain.laravel.com work accurately
6. But When subdomain.laravel.com/home there is a notice 404 not found
7. But in projects home controller having index function is existed.

Comment: Please share the whole scenario. It is not sufficient info to solve your routing issue.

Answer (score 0):

more like a server configuration issue. Make sure to point the document root to `public/` and that the file `public/index.php` is catching all requests:

nginx:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

more on https://laravel.com/docs/master/deployment

Answer (score 0):

Put subdomain routes firstly before
Route::get('/') of main domain